# How can i change the following LINQ query as normal sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-server-2008

I am having a query i need this to be as a plain sql query can any one help me. Also is there any alternate way with out using `NorthWindDatacontext` as per in the code mentioneedMy code is as follows

```
private void FetchData(int take, int pageSize)
{           
  using (NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext())
  {
    var query = from p in dc.Customers
         .OrderBy(o => o.ContactName)
          .Take(take)
            .Skip(pageSize)
        select new
                        {
                          ID = p.CustomerID,
                            Name = p.ContactName,
                            Count = dc.Customers.Count()
                        };

            PagedDataSource page = new PagedDataSource();
            page.AllowCustomPaging = true;
            page.AllowPaging = true;
            page.DataSource = query;
            page.PageSize = 10;
            Repeater1.DataSource = page;
            Repeater1.DataBind();

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                RowCount = query.First().Count;
                CreatePagingControl();
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried as per `Jon` but i am unable to get the desired result can any one help me

```
(SELECT [t1].[CustomerID] AS [ID], [t1].[ContactName] AS [Name], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t2]
    ) AS [Count]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (10) [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[ContactName]
    FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0]
    ORDER BY [t0].[ContactName]
    ) AS [t1]
ORDER BY [t1].[ContactName]
```

Comment: May I recommend to you `LINQPad` (http://www.linqpad.net/)? This awesome tool will allow you to execute your LINQ query against your database and to also see its T-SQL translation.

Comment: Did you mean to use pageSize in skip but hardcode 10 in page.PageSize?

Comment: You can also use SQL Server Profiler to see the queries that are executed against your DB. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

Comment: BTW - I'm not a .NET user so it would be really interesting to know what LINQ actually produces in this case.

Comment: @RoccoC5: Great suggestion - I've edited it into my answer; I hope you don't mind. If you want to add your own answer instead, I'm happy to remove it so you get the appropriate credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the SQL produced by your LINQ query, per LINQPad, where `@p0` is the number of rows to Skip:

```
SELECT [t3].[CustomerID] AS [ID], [t3].[ContactName] AS [Name], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Customers] AS [t4]
    ) AS [Count]
FROM (
    SELECT [t2].[CustomerID], [t2].[ContactName], [t2].[ROW_NUMBER]
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t1].[ContactName]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t1].[CustomerID], [t1].[ContactName]
        FROM (
            SELECT TOP (10) [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[ContactName]
            FROM [Customers] AS [t0]
            ORDER BY [t0].[ContactName]
            ) AS [t1]
        ) AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[ROW_NUMBER] > @p0
    ) AS [t3]
ORDER BY [t3].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

Comment: SO i should write some sort of store procedure for this to implement right

Comment: @Ramakrishna you don't need a SPROC - just execute it via ADO.NET or `ExecuteQuery<T>` - or something like "dapper"

Comment: Actually i am trying to implement this example [Repeater]http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=345. Any alternative to do in the exact way he does

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way in my view is to see what LINQ to SQL is doing.

Use [`DataContext.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) to write out the query information to a log of some kind (e.g. to a `StringWriter` whose contents you can print out afterwards). It won't always be the cleanest SQL possible, but it's a good starting point IMO.

I realise this doesn't answer the question for your *specific* query, but it's trying to teach you to fish as opposed to giving you a fish, as it were :)

EDIT: Using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) as suggested by RoccoC5 in comments is another great way of seeing the SQL generated for a LINQ query.

Comment: Can i have the sample query on my requirement as per that.

Comment: @Ramakrishna: Not from me, no. I don't have SQL installed on this machine. Presumably you are able to run the code you've shown though, so why not just make the change to log the SQL? You can do this with a *lot* less effort than I can at this stage.